# How can we listen for errors that do not trigger window.onerror?

Tags: javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror states:

> Note that some/many error events do not trigger window.onerror, you have to listen for them specifically.

1. Could you please provide some examples of errors that do not trigger `window.onerror`? I know `SyntaxError` is one of them.
2. Could you please provide a small code example to show how we can listen for such errors? Can we listen for `SyntaxError` too?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`window.onerror` is triggered whether it was a syntax or runtime error. [This page from quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html) has lists of what error events it will and will not catch.

> Could you please provide a small code example to show how we can
>   listen for such errors? Can we listen for SyntaxError too?

For a small code example to show how we can listen for such errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <script  type="text/javascript">
           window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
               alert(errorMsg + lineNumber);
               // alert("This is a stack trace! Wow! --> %s", error.stack);
            };
       </script>
    </head>

    <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        //var x=document.getElementById("demo").value; //uncomment and run to see
        document.write('careless to close the parentheses?'; // ')' is not given
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

running this example in your browser will pop up an alert message similar to this:

> JavaScript error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list on line
>   26 for *page_url*

In the above example: `window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber)`, the arguments are:

1. `message`: the error message (DOMString)
2. `url`: the URL of the file containing the error (DOMString)
3. `linenumber`: the line number where the error occurred (unsigned long)

If you run the same example by putting `var x=document.getElementById("demo").value;` instead of the code with syntax error(as i have shown in the example), it will also be caught by the `window.onerror()` function and will show an alert message similar to this:

> JavaScript error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null on
>   line 25 for *page_url*

*window.onerror* acts something like a global try/catch block, allowing you to gracefully handle([even with server logging](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/#logging)) uncaught exceptions you didn’t expect to see:

- uncaught exceptions

  1. `throw "some messages"`
  2. `call_something_undefined()`;
  3. `cross_origin_iframe.contentWindow.document;`, a security exception
- some more compile error

  1. `<script>{</script>`
  2. `<script>for(;)</script>`
  3. `<script>"oops</script>`
  4. `setTimeout("{", 10);`, it will attempt to compile the first argument as a script

But two major issues described [here](https://mikewest.org/2013/08/debugging-runtime-errors-with-window-onerror) nicely:

1. Unlike a local try/catch block, the window.onerror handler doesn’t
   have direct access to the exception object, and is executed in the
   global context rather than locally where the error occurred. That
   means that developers don’t have access to a call stack, and can’t
   build a call stack themselves by walking up the chain of a method’s
   callers.
2. Browsers go to great lengths to sanitize the data provided to the
   handler in order to prevent unintentional data leakage from
   cross-origin scripts. If you host your JavaScript on a CDN (as you
   ought), you’ll get “Script error.”, “”, and 0 in the above handler.
   That’s not particularly helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please answer my second question too: `Could you please provide a small code example to show how we can listen for such errors?`

Comment: Did you try running the example i have given in the answer ? I used safari 5.1.7 and Firefox 24.0 to test

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am quite busy with other things now. I'll try running the example you have provided as soon as I get time and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: One more thing, i forgot to put the **compatibility list: Chrome 13+, Firefox 6.1+, Internet Explorer 5.5+, (Opera 12+ ?), Safari 5.1+**

Comment: (1) [A stack trace may eventually get passed too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17687410/822138). (2) [CORS scripts can send error messages across domains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11118927/822138).

Comment: yes `window.onError = function (message, filename, lineno, colno, error)` where `error.stack` can be use to trace it, but as much as i know it is not still available in all browser. Thanks for mentioning